# Column "name_c" not found error when running a query on H2

Tags: java, h2, in-memory-database

I'm working with an in-memory instance of H2 for unit tests and I'm trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT name AS name_c FROM users ORDER BY lower(name_c)
```

(The real query is much more complicated but this simple query has the same symptom)

And I receive the following exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "NAME_C" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT name AS "name_c" FROM users ORDER BY lower(name_c) [42122-163]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:138)
    at org.h2.expression.Function.optimize(Function.java:1705)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:799)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1121)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:164)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at com.name.dal.Connection.executeQuery(Connection.java:462)
    at com.name.model.users.UserTest.testTest(UserTest.java:324)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Anyone knows why?

I'm creating the db using the following connection string:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:db1;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=60;IGNORECASE=TRUE
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try to change `ORDER BY lower(name_c)` into `ORDER BY lower(name)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use lower(name_c). lower(name) works fine. In my real query, name_c isn't a direct column but a calculated column from a query that is run from within the select clause.
Something like:
SELECT (SELECT name FROM other_users WHERE ...) AS name_c FROM users

Answer (score 1):

Column aliases are only available in the `order by` clause if they are used as is (alone). This is the same behavior as with other databases (according to my test, PostgreSQL and Derby). There are some databases that do support what you want (MySQL for example), but this is not part of the SQL standard. So for example:

```
create table test(id int primary key, name varchar(255));
insert into test values(1, 'hello');
insert into test values(2, 'world');
```

This works with all databases I tested:

```
select name as c_name from test order by c_name;
select name as c_name from test order by lower(name);
```

With this data, the following query failed for me with PostgreSQL, Apache Derby, and H2. It works with MySQL:

```
select name as c_name from test order by lower(c_name);
```